# How to debug the PHP error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS"

Tags: php, laravel, ovh

I try to host in ovh and I have this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/plandetrw/pavegalet/public/index.php on line 49

I think it's error php but I don't know how I can change php version because when I go in 'hosting plan ' and after in domain in configuration don't have for change php version because my client have multisite (few websites). How I can resolve this error? My version php it's 7.3 in my project.

When it's in local I don't have an error, only when I host. How I can resolve this?

Comment: We would need to see the code in `index.php` in order to help. Basically, you have invalid PHP in there. If you can run/test it locally, that might help you too - while you can develop on a remote host, it is easier/faster to do it locally.

Comment: @halfer in local it's worked

Comment: Possibly OVH is running with the wrong version of PHP - do a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` remotely and see if you get what you expect.